# Resize whiskers (width) in a ggplot boxplot with a grouping variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, r-whisker

When I resize whiskers in a boxplot using `geom="errorbar , width="`the center line (from stat_boxplot) with whiskers moves, so I get two lines:

- How can I avoid that when I resize? Especifically, I would like to make whisker width smaller thant boxplot width.
- How do I hide the line from boxplot? (An answer for the first question would solves the problem, but I'm curious).

```
library(car)
data(Salaries)    # 'data(Salaries, package=car)' doesn't work 
library(ggplot2)

p<- ggplot(Salaries, aes(x=rank, y=salary, fill=sex)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom= 'errorbar', width = 0.3) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  labs(title="Salary by Rank and Sex", x="Rank", y="Salary") 
  
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: what do you want to resize. Please clarify.

Comment: I want to resize whiskers width, make it smaller that boxplot width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can get your desired outcome by adjusting the position of your `stat_boxplot()`. For me, it appears correct by adding the following argument: `position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)`. It was trial and error to get the correct value of 0.75.

```
p <- ggplot(Salaries, aes(x=rank, y=salary, fill=sex)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom= 'errorbar' , width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75) ) +
  
  geom_boxplot() +
  
  labs(title="Salary by Rank and Sex", x="Rank", y="Salary") 

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much, ```position=position_dodge(width=)``` solves it.